# Compatible versions of Spring boot,elasticsearch and spring data elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have been developing a simple java programming using spring boot,elastic search and spring data elastic search.

I am able to do the elastic search successfully with below versions 
         1) spring boot 1.3.5
         2) spring-data-elasticsearch 1.3.4.RELEASE
         3) elasticsearch 1.3.2

but when i upgraded to the below versions,one of my service class annotated with @service annotation showing error as

> "The type
>   org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.SuggestBuilder$SuggestionBuilder
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files".

```
     1) spring boot 1.5.1.RELEASE
     2) spring-data-elasticsearch 2.1.0.RELEASE
     3) elasticsearch 5.0.1
     4) org.elasticsearch.client.transport 5.1.1
```

is it the issue with incompatible verions? if yes,please help me what is the compatible versions of spring boot,elasticsearch and spring data elasticsearch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a compatible set of versions as Spring Data Elasticsearch doesn't support Elasticsearch 5.0 yet. See [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-285) that's tracking some of the work to support 5.0.

Generally speaking, rather than trying to find compatible versions yourself, you should let Spring Boot's dependency management take care of that for you. If you are overriding that dependency management to use a new major version of a dependency, there is a very good chance that it won't work.

Comment: thank you so much Andy.
As you suggested removed all overridden versions from my pom file and jar versions are managed by spring boot now
overidden org.elasticsearch.client.transport 5.1.1 version which is useful for creating TransportClient object.
when iam trying to run my spring boot application,getting exception as "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.plugins.NetworkPlugin".Could you please help me in understand the issue.

Comment: This is the piece of code which iam using to create TransportClient object
   Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
         TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
         client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9300)));
         return client;

Comment: try to remove PreBuildTransportClient and replace just TransportClient.builder().., something like this --> @Bean
 public Client client() throws UnknownHostException{
  
     
  Settings settings = Settings.builder()
    .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
    .build();
  TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build()
  .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9200));
  
     return client;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data ES 3.0.0M4 release is compatible with ES 5.0 - Ref -
[DATAES-285](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-285)