# Elasticsearch version for Spring Boot 2.1

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, elasticsearch

In my **Spring Boot**(**2.0.5**) project I was using **Elasticsearch**(**5.6.9**). However, due to some bugs in testing environment we are moving to Spring boot(**2.1.0**).
When I run the application the following message comes up:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.PutMappingRequestBuilder.execute()Lorg/elasticsearch/action/ActionFuture; but it does not exist. Its class, org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.PutMappingRequestBuilder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/5.6.9/elasticsearch-5.6.9.jar!/org/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/mapping/put/PutMappingRequestBuilder.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/5.6.9/elasticsearch-5.6.9.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.PutMappingRequestBuilder


Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Current pom.xml file**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <elasticsearch.version>5.6.9</elasticsearch.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!--...others...-->     

        <!--ELASTICSEARCH-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
            <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Previous pom.xml file** which worked fine:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <elasticsearch.version>5.6.9</elasticsearch.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!--...others...-->     

        <!--ELASTICSEARCH-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
            <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Can someone tell which version of elasticsearch is compatible with Spring Boot 2.1.0?
I read through similar questions which were outdated. 
[Compatible versions of Spring boot,elasticsearch and spring data elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135906/compatible-versions-of-spring-boot-elasticsearch-and-spring-data-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go to [Spring Boot project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot) Github repository and check any dependency version:

- In Spring Boot 2.0.x Elasticsearch version is defined as 5.6.16 ([link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.0.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L63))
- In Spring Boot 2.1.x Elasticsearch version is defined as 6.4.3
  ([link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.1.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L64))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's still actual, but the first thing you need to try is to add core Elasticsearch library, because REST client depends on it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>6.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```